# proper way of displaying and editing date

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am displaying a date from a database in my form within a text box but the format of the date from the database is `mm/dd/yyyy` how can I display it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Is it okay to edit my date form as `mm/dd/yyyy`?

here is my code:

```
Dim search As String = String.Empty
    search &= "select * from stocks "
    search &= "where build_number=@build"

    If ebuildnumber.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Input Build Number Before Searching")
    End If

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=pc_parts;user=admin;password=12345;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = search
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@build", ebuildnumber.Text)
            End With

            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    With reader
                        reader.Read()
                        ebrand.Text = .GetValue(1)
                        epart.Text = .GetValue(2)
                        equantity.Text = .GetValue(3)
                        edate.Text = .GetValue(4)
                        reader.Close()
                    End With
                Else
                    MsgBox("Build Number Not Found")
                End If
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: when you say *Is it okay to edit my date form as mm/dd/yyyy?* what do you mean? Dont you want to display the date as `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: is this Windows Form or ASP? And I really hope those are fake login/password

Comment: In a proper database, the date should be date/datetime variable. This mean, the format when doing CRUD operation doesn't mater at all since you would be using the Date class.

Comment: in inserting or adding a new record on date the format should be in yyyy-mm-dd. but in displaying the date on text box the format is mm/dd/yyyy.
is that gonna cause on error on updating when the format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: its windows form. and im practicing thats why the login and password are like that

Comment: Why involve a text box at all? There's a [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) control that understands .NET `DateTime` values. ADO.Net knows how to translate .NETs `DateTime` into SQL Server's `datetime` (or `date` or `datetime2`). Stick with the right data types and there *are* no formats (e.g. .NETs `DateTime` is just the count of 100ns intervals since 01/01/0001)

Comment: i want to display it on text box i might expect some user dont know what to do with datetime picker

Comment: @Ndrangheta - the subset of users who won't know what to do with a datetime picker but will perfectly interact with a text input (and not present you with e.g. `30/02/2017` or `02/30/2017`) is vanishingly small. Treating everything as strings is the *source* of errors, not the *cure*.

Answer (score 2):

When you put the date on the text control you convert Date to string

```
Dim formatedDate as String = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But when user press `SAVE` button you converted to date again before send to DB

```
Dim updateDate as DateTime = 
      DateTime.ParseExact(Text1.text, 
                          "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: im using vb.net

Comment: The answerer accidentally left semi-colons in, but otherwise this is perfectly valid VB

Comment: the    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture doesnt read as a code on vb.net